# Probability 4-ball Urn Question

Tags: probability

An Urn contains four balls numbered $1$ through $4$.  The balls are selected one at a time without replacement.  A match occurs of the ith ball is selected on the ith draw.

What is the probability of at least one match?

To me, the probability of at least one match should be $1-p$(no matches).

To have no matches, you have to miss the 1st, miss the 2nd, and miss the 3rd (if you miss the 1st 3, you must miss the 4th)

Therefore, it seems like it should be $1- \left(\dfrac{3}{4}×\dfrac{2}{3}×\dfrac{1}{2}×1\right)$ but apparently that is not correct.

I can get the right answer by the inclusion/exclusion principal but can someone tell me what I did wrong above.

Thanks

Comment: i feel your answer is right, waiting for other responses.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 2):

The probability of missing the first is indeed $3/4$. However, if the first ball selected is "2," then the conditional probability of missing the second is $1$; if the first ball is not "2," then the conditional probability of missing the second is $2/3$.

The inclusion-exclusion approach is the correct approach, and you mentioned that you were successful with it.

Also, as leonbloy pointed out in the comments, the outcomes of "no matches" are known as [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Ah---great, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you treat the probabilities at each draw as though they were independent, when they're not.

Take the first draw.  That one is correct; there is indeed a $\frac{3}{4}$ probability that the first ball drawn is not number $1$.

But the probability that the second ball drawn is not number $2$ is only $\frac{2}{3}$ if the first ball drawn was *not* number $2$.  Otherwise, the probability is $1$.

Likewise, the probability that the third ball drawn is not number $3$ is only $\frac{1}{2}$ if neither of the first two balls drawn was number $3$.  And likewise for the fourth ball being number $4$.  The fact that you have a $1$ there should have tipped you off; the pattern should have led you to a $0$, but that would have meant there was no probability of no match.

Comment: got it---thanks